# How to build and execute wasm code on-the-client web page?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

Is it possible to build and execute wasm code on the client web page? I do not care from which source language - js\ts\C++... I just want to have the capability to build it on the fly and execute and be sure it was compiled on the client.

Answer (score 0):

For Clang it was done. One may look at https://github.com/binji/wasm-clang repo [example](https://binji.github.io/wasm-clang/)